# What are the downsides of my Mergesort implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

Could I ask you to evaluate my implementation of mergesort?

I think that it's consistent with \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ complexity but has a downside that I create a new `result` array at each step of recursion.

How do you think it can be improved?

```
public int[] mergesort(final int[] input) {
    return mergesort(input, 0, input.length - 1);
}

private int[] mergesort(final int[] input, final int left, final int right) {
    final int[] result;
    if (left < right) {
        final int m = (right - left) / 2 + left;
        final int[] leftPart = mergesort(input, left, m);
        final int[] rightPart = mergesort(input, m + 1, right);
        result = new int[leftPart.length + rightPart.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < leftPart.length && j < rightPart.length) {
            if (leftPart[i] <= rightPart[j]) {
                result[i + j] = leftPart[i++];
            } else {
                result[i + j] = rightPart[j++];
            }
        }
        while (i < leftPart.length) {
            result[i + j] = leftPart[i++];
        }
        while (j < rightPart.length) {
            result[i + j] = rightPart[j++];
        }
    } else {
        result = new int[]{input[left]};
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Why are you returning a new array instead of directly sorting the input array? If we create 2 temporary arrays (left and right part) and then merge them back into the input array we don't need to return a new one (and can optimise later on).

```
private static void mergesort(int[] input, final int left, final int right) {
    //quick note here, I flipped your if check so we can return earlier.
    //This makes it easier to follow the complete flow
    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }
    //edge cases handled before this point. Can continue with actual algorithm after.
    final int m = (right - left) / 2 + left;
    mergesort(input, left, m);
    mergesort(input, m + 1, right);

    int[] leftPart = new int[m - left + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < leftPart.length-1;i++){
        leftPart[i] = input[left + i];
    }
    int[] rightPart = new int[right - m];
    for(int i = 0; i<rightPart.length-1;i++){
        rightPart[i] = input[m + i];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < leftPart.length && j < rightPart.length) {
        if (leftPart[i] <= rightPart[j]) {
            input[i + j] = leftPart[i++];
        } else {
            input[i + j] = rightPart[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < leftPart.length) {
        input[i + j] = leftPart[i++];
    }
    while (j < rightPart.length) {
        input[i + j] = rightPart[j++];
    }
}
```

Now that we sort the input array directly theres one major memory optimisation we can do. We no longer need to store the right half in a temporary array anymore. Instead we can directly copy from the input array since the "current" spot is always smaller or equal than the index of the right part we're handling.

```
private static void mergesort(int[] input, final int left, final int right) {
    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }

    final int m = (right - left) / 2 + left;
    mergesort(input, left, m);
    mergesort(input, m + 1, right);

    int[] leftPart = new int[m - left+1];
    //note: arraycopy is usually more efficient than manually copying an array.
    System.arraycopy(input, left, leftPart, 0, leftPart.length);

    int current = left;
    int currentLeft = 0;
    int currentRight = m+1;

    while (currentLeft < leftPart.length && currentRight <= right) {
        if (leftPart[currentLeft] <= input[currentRight]) {
            input[current++] = leftPart[currentLeft++];
        } else {
            input[current++] = input[currentRight++];
        }
    }
    while (currentLeft < leftPart.length) {
        input[current++] = leftPart[currentLeft++];
    }
    //no need to handle remaining right part, as it's already in the input array
}
```

Some extra notes:

I renamed some variables to make it more clear what they mean. Even though `i` and `j` are common enough for a simple loop, it wasn't obvious enough anymore once the right index started from halfway the part of the array that needed to be sorted.

I made the method static. It doesn't depend on any state of the class it's in so could be put into a more general utility class instead.

`System.arraycopy` is more performant than manually copying all elements into another array.